# Kendo Hierarchy Grid clear selection

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am playing with this example by Kendo: http://dojo.telerik.com/EneFe

I have modified it so that the rows are selectable (selectable:true).

I have added a button on the top which calls the grid.clearSelection() function.

This is supposed to clear all selection but it does not clear the selection of rows that are selected in the dropdown table. (Recreate: click on the first row "Nancy", expand it and click on "10258 - Austria", then click the "Clear Selection" button and only "Nancy" will clear)

Is the function not working properly or am I misusing it?

In any case - how can I achieve a total clearing of all selected rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because they are two separate grids. Check this:

http://dojo.telerik.com/EneFe/2